# R: How to draw a diagonal line in a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a graph with ggplot2 and I would like to add a diagonal line from bottom-left to up-right and asign a color to this line. How can I do that?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=DRTG, y=ORTG)) +
  geom_point(colour = "#000000") + 
  ggtitle("Gráfico: Ratio Defensivo / Ratio Ofensivo (hasta jornada 8)") +
  geom_text(label=rownames(data), colour = "#000000", nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0.75, size = 4, vjust = "inward", hjust = "inward", check_overlap = F) +
  geom_point(data=pointMedia, aes(x=mediaDRTG, y=mediaORTG, colour="red", size = 1)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = pointMedia[, "mediaDRTG"], colour = "green") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = pointMedia[, "mediaORTG"], colour = "blue") +
  geom_text(data=pointMedia, aes(x=mediaDRTG, y=mediaORTG, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0.75, label="Liga DIA")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

**Edit I:**

I have added + geom_abline(intercept = 120, slope = 0) and I don't get anything :( What am I doing wrong?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=DRTG, y=ORTG)) +
  geom_point(colour = "#000000") + 
  ggtitle("Gráfico: Ratio Defensivo / Ratio Ofensivo (hasta jornada 8)") +
  geom_text(label=rownames(data), colour = "#000000", nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0.75, size = 4, vjust = "inward", hjust = "inward", check_overlap = F) +
  geom_point(data=pointMedia, aes(x=mediaDRTG, y=mediaORTG, colour="red", size = 1)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = pointMedia[, "mediaDRTG"], colour = "green") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = pointMedia[, "mediaORTG"], colour = "blue") +
  geom_text(data=pointMedia, aes(x=mediaDRTG, y=mediaORTG, label="Liga DIA"), nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0.75) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 120, slope = 0) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

**Edit II:**

I have setting intercept and slope to this values and I get this pic

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=DRTG, y=ORTG)) +
  geom_point(colour = "#000000") + 
  ggtitle("Gráfico: Ratio Defensivo / Ratio Ofensivo (hasta jornada 8)") +
  geom_text(label=rownames(data), colour = "#000000", nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0.75, size = 4, vjust = "inward", hjust = "inward", check_overlap = F) +
  geom_point(data=pointMedia, aes(x=mediaDRTG, y=mediaORTG, colour="red", size = 1)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = pointMedia[, "mediaDRTG"], colour = "green") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = pointMedia[, "mediaORTG"], colour = "blue") +
  geom_text(data=pointMedia, aes(x=mediaDRTG, y=mediaORTG, label="Liga DIA"), nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0.75) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 11.6, slope = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

And what I want is that the end of the line is in the upper right corner of the graph.

I want to draw a line from bottom left corner of the graph until upper right corner of the graph.

Comment: Use `geom_abline`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample input data and the code you are already using to draw your plot so far. Most likely you want `?geom_abline`

Comment: `+ geom_abline(slope,intercept)`

Comment: Thank you Mouad_S. Do you know any example of the values of slope and intercept?

Comment: 120 it is outside of your x-axis. Also slope 0 will give you an horizontal line

Comment: With this geom_abline(intercept = 11.6, slope = 1) I've got a diagonal line, but not what I want. I don't know why I have to set intercept = 11.6 put the line on (0, 0) ...

Comment: And where do you want the line?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Try this: `geom_abline(intercept =0 , slope = 1)+ xlim(70,120)+ylim(70,120)`

Comment: Oooooooh!!! It Works!!! Thank you so much S Rivero!!!

Answer (score 2):

Given nobody answered this query, I figured I would add one here so people can quickly reference it rather than skim through the comments, as I found this to be a useful thread when I first googled it. First off, you can quickly and automatically draw a line across a `ggplot` function without even using the `aes` argument.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_abline()
```

Like so:

[image: Diagonal]

Of course this isn't super useful on its own. Given there wasn't any reproducible data given, I can provide an example so people can try. Using the `iris` data, we can draw a simple line across the page if we want.

```
ggplot(iris,
       aes(x=Petal.Length,
           y=Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline()
```

[image: crapo plot]

Now of course that isn't super helpful either. One way we can make it more useful is by applying it to regression lines. We first call the `lm` function to get us a slope and intercept value, then plug those into the `geom_abline` function, then color it blue.

```
lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,
              data = iris) # int: -0.361, slope = .4158

ggplot(iris,
       aes(x=Petal.Length,
           y=Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(slope = .4158,
              intercept = -0.3631,
              color="blue")
```

[image: reg line]

Maybe we want to establish cutoff zones in our plot (perhaps there is some theoretical reason that values should only lie within a certain range on the plot. We can create a couple of dashed red lines above and below the data points.

```
ggplot(iris,
       aes(x=Petal.Length,
           y=Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(slope = .4158,
              intercept = -0.3631,
              color="blue")+
  geom_abline(slope = .6,
              intercept = 0.1,
              color="red",
              linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_abline(slope = .4,
              intercept = -1,
              color="red",
              linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Really there are an infinite number of ways to use `geom_abline` and its variants, as such it would be good to explore others like `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` if you have time.